# Trying to change my Application insight data sampling limit level to 12.5% using powerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

Trying to change my Application insight data sampling limit level to 12.5% using powerShell.

I am unable to find the command to update the application data sampling through powershell script

Comment: What results do you get when you check google for the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change Data sampling Percentage, please refer to the following script

```
#update
$r =Get-AzResource -Name <resource name> -ResourceType Microsoft.Insights/Components -ResourceGroupName <group name>
 write-host $r.Properties.SamplingPercentage -BackgroundColor red
$r.Properties.SamplingPercentage=12.5
$r| Set-AzResource -Force

#check
$r =Get-AzResource -Name 219bowman -ResourceType Microsoft.Insights/Components -ResourceGroupName 0730BowmanWindow
 write-host $r.Properties.SamplingPercentage -BackgroundColor red
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jim Xu. it is used for me